# Why is unsigned int storing negative values when unsigned short int isn't? The unsigned int value is not wrapping around as it should be

Tags: c, integer, unsigned-integer

Compiler used is gcc compiler installed using mingw in Windows 10

Tried the same in online gcc compiler and it also gave me the same results

Code:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int n = -1;
    unsigned short int y = -1;
    printf("n is unsigned int n = %d\ny is unsigned short int y = %d\n",n,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\LENOVO\Downloads> gcc .\test.c -o out
PS C:\Users\LENOVO\Downloads> .\out
n is unsigned int n = -1
y is unsigned short int y = 65535
```

Comment: Try `%u` format specifier within printf.

Comment: `printf` receives its arguments in `int`-size slots, hence the short variable is received as `0x0000FFFF`, hence interpreted during runtime as 65535.

Comment: You are not comparing like with like. The `unsigned int` stores the value `0xFFFFFFFF` but the `unsigned short` stores `0xFFFF` which can held by `int` whereas the first can not. By the time they are printed there is no memory that the initialisation values were negative.

Comment: `%d` advises `printf` to interprete the data as a decimal number (with sign) so it prints it as a signed int.

Comment: Note that integer arguments for a variadic function like `printf`, that are a smaller type than `int`, are promoted to `int`.

Comment: As a user, you are responsible to provide the correct format specifiers for `printf`. The correct ones for `unsigned` are `u`, `x` or `o`, the correct ones for `unsigned short` are prefixed with `h`.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni: The statement “When you pass a integer to `printf` associating it to format specifier `%d`, it is converted to `int`” is false. Arguments to `printf` after the first are promoted according to the default argument promotions. This has nothing to do with `%d`. It converts narrow integer types to `int`, but it does not affect `unsigned` and so does not occur in OP’s case. When an `unsigned` is passed for `%d`, the resulting behavior is not defined by the C standard. In OP’s case, it appears the bits have been reinterpreted as an `int`. Reinterpretation is different from…

Comment: … conversion. Conversion is defined in the C standard according to the values represented. Reinterpretation proceeds according to the bits. Conveying this incorrectly to students means they have to unlearned it later and then learn the correct information, which is harder than learning correctly in the first place.

Comment: @EricPostpischil actually that's not far from what I meant. I understand that in language standards correct terms are important, but you also have to understand that non native English speakers might (wrongly) treat as synonims terms that actually are not synonims. In particular sometimes I do mistakes on terms that do exist in my native languages. IMHO the core answer was valid: 1) think how data types are represented 2) see what happens _promoting_ them to signed integers 3) See what happens if we _reinterpret_ them (correct?) like they were signed integers. (continued)

Comment: ... So basically my goal was trying to show to the OP that representing each kind of data in their minds helps to understand what's going on. Again: strictness in the terms used is gold and provides value to SO knowledge. But SO is a collaborative community, so... Anyway, thanks for the feedback..

Answer (score -1):

Implementing a function which yields the equivalence of your `printf` function-call:

```
void func(int x, ...)
{
    int n = ((int*)&x)[1]; // n = 0xFFFFFFFF = -1
    int y = ((int*)&x)[2]; // y = 0x0000FFFF = 65535
}
```

This is platform-dependent of course, since the size of `int` is not necessarily 32 bits on every platform, so more generally, `printf` receives each one of its arguments (starting from the second argument) in either an `int`-size slot or a `long long`-size slot.

It interprets each argument according to the corresponding `%`-type in the input string (first argument) that it receives, so when you pass a `short` argument, it is "extended" to `int` and then pushed into the stack before `printf` is called.

In a much worst case, you'd be passing a `long long`-size value (for example, a `double` value), and indicate an `int`-size type in the input string (for example, `%d`). This would cause `printf` to "go out of synch" and eventually behave in an ambiguous (undefined) manner.

Comment: Why would one take the address of an `int` and then cast that to `int*`?

Comment: @JensGustedt: Taking the address of the first argument in the stack and using it in order to compute the addresses of the remaining arguments. This code is not guaranteed to work by the standard, since the standard doesn't dictate that the compiler should use a stack for function calls. But it is the case in every compiler that I've ever worked with, so I added it as an example, in order clarify the internal behavior of `printf`.

Comment: But why the cast? I still don't understand. And by the way, accessing `[1]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @JensGustedt: It would yield undefined behavior if you called the function without passing the two additional arguments that it expects. Just like calling `printf("%d %d")` would!

Comment: No, accessing an element outside the array bounds is always undefined, regardless.

Comment: Or writing the C standard, perhaps?

Comment: @JensGustedt: What I meant to say is, that the purpose of this coding example is not to serve a solution for the given problem, or even more generally, because at some point somebody might port it from a platform where it works correctly to a platform where it doesn't, hence the *undefined behavior* argument becomes a strong incentive. But it can still be used in order to illustrate the internal behavior of a variadic function, which is what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm aware of the fanatically religious attitude of many of the users here towards the sacred rule of *undefined behavior* (though shalt not bare its name in vain), and I knew straight onward that any answer here would automatically get a couple of dislikes from one of you guys. But I nevertheless chose to use that coding example in order to try and illustrate the issue to the dude who has asked the question.

Comment: No, it dos not work in practice. I tested your code with Clang 11.0.0 on macOS 10.14.6 and called `func(1, 2, 3)`. It showed −462910840 for `n` and 73896 for `y`. Aside from the fact that many ABIs pass some arguments in registers, not memory, some compilers are optimizing using pointer provenance, so `(&x)[1]` will not yield the memory after an `int` `x` even if the desired argument is there. Furthermore, your comment to Jens Gustedt about occupation is rude and inappropriate. And while you may think being loose about specifications is okay, computers are machines and will not tolerate it.